# Dynamic Table with label and button as Columns

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I want to create a dynamic table in C# with `Adding and deleting of row` dynamically  in which I need `two columns`, `Column 1 as label` and `column 2 as button` and I want that table to be add rows from some other methods..

and Clicking of the button of column 2 , I want particular row to be delete only..
for example:

```
COL1      COL2

label     button(to delete row)
```

(add)

I am trying is:
In aspx

```
 <asp:Table border="1" id="Table1" runat="server">
 </asp:Table>
```

in C#

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            for (int j = 0; j <2; j++)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();

                // Add the control to the TableCell

                LinkButton tb1 = new LinkButton();

                if (IsOdd(j))
                {
                    Label tb = new Label();
                    tb.Width = 100;

                    // Set a unique ID for each zTextBox added
                    tb.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                    tb.Text = "asdad";
                    cell.Controls.Add(tb);

                }
                else
                {
                    tb1.Width = 100;

                    // Set a unique ID for each zTextBox added
                    tb1.ID = "TextBoxRow_" + i + "Col_" + j;
                    tb1.Text = "asdad";
                    cell.Controls.Add(tb1);
                }
                // Add the TableCell to the TableRow
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }
   Table1.Rows.Add(row);

        }
```

Comment: Are you running into some sort of trouble? What is your exact question?

Comment: You can also try by adding rows to `DataTable` in `c#` and binding `DataTable` to `GridView`, `DataGrid` or `Repeater`.

Comment: @Timusan if i click on the any Linkbutton .. this whole methods calls again (for loop).. i dont know where i am doing mistake

Comment: @Bharadwaj but I think we cannot add the button in DataTable

Comment: hey @user3226440 , are you calling it in Page_Load  ?  if so use it inside  `if(!IsPostBack) { ..... }`

Comment: Man, you have to have your table and things in an update panel.

Comment: You can add button to your `GridView` or `DataGrid` and then can bind the data to it.